# Is it possible to transform a CSV file with date as index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently try to convert a CSV with python3 to a new format.
My later goal is to add some information to this file with pandas.
Thinks like "is the date a weekday or weekend?".

To achieve this, however, I have to overcome the first hurdle.

I need to transform my CSV file from this:

```
date,hour,price
2018-10-01,0-1,59.53
2018-10-01,1-2,56.10
2018-10-01,2-3,51.41
2018-10-01,3-4,47.38
2018-10-01,4-5,47.59
2018-10-01,5-6,51.61
2018-10-01,6-7,69.13
2018-10-01,7-8,77.32
2018-10-01,8-9,84.97
2018-10-01,9-10,79.56
2018-10-01,10-11,73.70
2018-10-01,11-12,71.63
2018-10-01,12-13,63.15
2018-10-01,13-14,60.24
2018-10-01,14-15,56.18
2018-10-01,15-16,53.00
2018-10-01,16-17,53.37
2018-10-01,17-18,60.42
2018-10-01,18-19,69.93
2018-10-01,19-20,75.00
2018-10-01,20-21,65.83
2018-10-01,21-22,53.86
2018-10-01,22-23,46.46
2018-10-01,23-24,42.50
2018-10-02,0-1,45.10
2018-10-02,1-2,44.10
2018-10-02,2-3,44.06
2018-10-02,3-4,43.70
2018-10-02,4-5,44.29
2018-10-02,5-6,48.13
2018-10-02,6-7,57.70
2018-10-02,7-8,68.21
2018-10-02,8-9,70.36
2018-10-02,9-10,54.53
2018-10-02,10-11,48.49
2018-10-02,11-12,46.19
2018-10-02,12-13,44.15
2018-10-02,13-14,30.79
2018-10-02,14-15,27.75
2018-10-02,15-16,30.74
2018-10-02,16-17,26.77
2018-10-02,17-18,38.68
2018-10-02,18-19,48.52
2018-10-02,19-20,49.03
2018-10-02,20-21,45.43
2018-10-02,21-22,32.04
2018-10-02,22-23,26.22
2018-10-02,23-24,1.08
2018-10-03,0-1,2.13
2018-10-03,1-2,0.10
...
```

to this:

```
date,0-1,1-2,2-3,3-4,4-5,5-6,6-7,7-8,8-9,...,23-24
2018-10-01,59.53,56.10,51.41,47.38,47.59,51.61,69.13,77.32,84.97,...,42.50
2018-10-02,45.10,44.10,44.06,43.70,44.29,....
2018-10.03,2.13,0.10,....
...
```

I've tried a lot with pandas DataFrames, but I can't come up with a solution.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df
```

```py
            date   hour  price
0     2018-10-01    0-1  59.53
1     2018-10-01    1-2  56.10
2     2018-10-01    2-3  51.41
3     2018-10-01    3-4  47.38
4     2018-10-01    4-5  47.59
5     2018-10-01    5-6  51.61
6     2018-10-01    6-7  69.13
7     2018-10-01    7-8  77.32
8     2018-10-01    8-9  84.97
```

The DataFrame should look like this.
But I don't manage to fill the DataFrame.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=['date'], columns=['date','0-1','1-2','2-3', '3-4', '4-5', '5-6', '6-7', '7-8', '8-9', '9-10', '10-11', '11-12', '12-13', '13-14', '14-15', '15-16', '16-17', '17-18', '18-19', '19-20', '20-21', '21-22', '22-23', '23-24'])
```

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
# pivot the dataframe with hour to the columns
df1 = df.set_index(['date','hour']).unstack(1)

# drop level-0 on columns
df1.columns = [ c[1] for c in df1.columns ]

# sort the column names by numeric order of hours (the number before '-')
df1 = df1.reindex(columns=sorted(df1.columns, key=lambda x: int(x.split('-')[0]))).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try using the `index_col` argument of `pd.read_csv()`, using integer labelling for the columns in the file:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

`read_csv` docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html); don't be put off by the alarming number of keyword arguments, one of them will often do what you need!

You may need to parse the first two columns as a date, then add a column for weekend based on a condition on the result. See the `parse_dates` and `infer_datetime_format` keyword arguments.